# Is it possible to get/where can I get consumer level paid support

Tags: support

I've installed Ubuntu on my parents' machines, but there are some consistant problems that I can't resolve. Unfortunately, setting the issues out to the different channels (ask ubuntu, forum) didn't help. Is there any way I can get paid support for individual customers, via Canonical or otherwise? *It seems Canonical doesn't offer this (anymore).*

Comment: Seems there is only Ubuntu advantage now http://www.ubuntu.com/management This is a bit much for a single user, why not add links to two or three of you most important issues in your question ? You never know who will see it.

Comment: @muru Reading your link, it seems this answer suggests paid support is available but this is no longer true as there links redirect to enterprise advantage pages, you may already know this but I comment just to clarify for others,.

Comment: Anyone filled in the form at http://www.canonical.com/services/contact-us with Industry=="Not Applicable (Self)" and got any reply from Canonical?

Answer (score 1):

There is something called Desktop Management in Ubuntu Advantage priced $105/year/machine

Source: http://www.ubuntu.com/management/ubuntu-advantage

If you want to know what is included in this price, there is a service description page, checkout Appendix 3 - Desktop support scope details:

http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/ubuntu-advantage/service-description#appendix-3